# How can i make 2 houses with 2 routers appear like 1 network? (Asus Merlin)

Tags: networking, router, openvpn, home-networking, asuswrt-merlin

I have two houses, with separate ISP connections, and separate Asus routers with merlin firmware.

I know how to setup a VPN where all traffic routes through one network, or the other network, so that it looks like they are all using the same public IP, but that is too aggressive.

I don't want one house to be eating at another house's bandwidth for regular internet usage.

Only when doing stuff like Upnp or rdp, would I want one house to use another house's bandwidth.

I've been reading that I might want something using openvpn TAP connection... Is there a mode in merlin Asus firmware that easily sets this up, or a guide specifically for my situation?

Comment: Appear to who? The local users or the outside world?

Answer (score 0):

Using the OpenVPN TAP connection won't help here. It's similar to the TUN connection, just on a different network layer.

One thing you can do is set up an OpenVPN connection with House 1 as the server and House 2 as the client. Normally, this would mean that House 2's Internet connection goes through House 1's ISP. However, you want to set up your routes on House 2's router such that only traffic to the other house's subnet travels over the VPN. The first step would be to delete the default route (i.e., the route that sends all traffic over OpenVPN). Then, you would need to add a route that sends traffic to House 1's subnet over the VPN.

As I don't own any Asus routers, I'm not aware of the specific options in the firmware. In addition, these steps could vary based on each house's subnet and the VPN subnet.